# Can't use Component Selectors with MUI v5 Emotion Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, babeljs, emotion

```js
import { Box, styled } from "@mui/material"
import { Body1 } from "elements/Typography"
export const ItemHeader = styled(Box)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;

  ${Body1} {
    span {
      margin-left: 0.5em;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.error.main};
    }
  }
`
```

I am Creating an mui emotion component with Component selectors, I already have setup
**babel.config.js** and installed @emotion/babel-plugin

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "@emotion",
      {
        importMap: {
          "@mui/system": {
            styled: {
              canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              styledBaseImport: ["@mui/system", "styled"]
            }
          },
          "@mui/material/styles": {
            styled: {
              canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              styledBaseImport: ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

But it is throwing the following error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
```

or

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
```

instead of

```
import {styled } from "@mui/material";
```

Comment: if I import from "@emotion/styled/macro" then I can't access theme object with styled components

Comment: Hey Darab, you can still customize your styles with the styled macro, check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-styled-macro-3mpri3)

Comment: Yes, I can customize with styled macro but I don't want a hack.
I want to know why it's not working I have done everything written in mui documentation

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and don’t know how suitable this solution is.

I have changed 'emotion' to 'styled-components' and can also use the theme prop while I write styles and Components Selector does work. I didn't notice any changes for myself.

**But you shouldn't use it if you are using SSR.**

https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/styled-components/